# Duda con array_rand

Tags: php, array

estoy empezando en el mundo del php y para ir aplicando lo que voy aprendiendo he decidido hacer una pequeña pagina web que emule el juego del poker, de dos arrays donde tengo definida la baraja, me salta una imagen de la carta en concreto, mi problema esta en que estas cartas se repiten, cosa que como ya sabeis no pasa en la realidad, entonces mi pregunta es como puedo eliminar o que no se repita esa carta de mi array:

```
<?php

$palos = array("P","T","C","D");
$cartas = array('2','3','4','5');

$palo = array_rand($palos,1);
$carta = array_rand($cartas,1);

$primeraCarta = $cartas[$carta] . $palos[$palo];

$palo2 = array_rand($palos,1);
$carta2 = array_rand($cartas,1);

$segundaCarta = $cartas[$carta2] .$palos[$palo2];



?>

<div class="contenedor">
<img src= "<?php echo $primeraCarta . '.png'; ?>"></img>
<img src= "<?php echo $segundaCarta . '.png'; ?>"></img>
</div>

<p> <?php if ( $carta == $carta2 || $carta2 == $carta) {    
    echo "Tienes pareja, "; 
} else {
    echo "No tienes pareja, ";
}

if ( $palo == $palo2 || $palo2 == $palo){
    echo "tambien tienes pareja de color";
} else {
    echo "no tienes pareja de color";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: He probado tu codigo en un sandbox online, y en general devuelve las cartas aleatorias. Puede ser que las imagenes .png que tienes esten repetidas y te este liando eso??? De todas formas, este tipo de funciones son pseudoaleatorias, por lo que puede ser que se repita con mucha mas frecuencia de lo que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un bucle que te compruebe si la segunda carta es igual a la primera carta e itere o salga del bucle en función del resultado. Por ejemplo:

```
$palos = array("P","T","C","D");
$cartas = array('2','3','4','5');

$palo = array_rand($palos,1);
$carta = array_rand($cartas,1);

$primeraCarta = $cartas[$carta] . $palos[$palo];

//defines inicialmente una variable a false y mientras esa variable no este a true, iteras
$nueva_carta = false;
while(!$nueva_carta){
    $palo2 = array_rand($palos,1);
    $carta2 = array_rand($cartas,1);

    $segundaCarta = $cartas[$carta2].$palos[$palo2];

    //compruebas si son distintas. Si lo son, sales directamente del bucle ya que el valor de $segundaCarta es el que te interesa.
    if($primeraCarta != $segundaCarta){
        $nueva_carta = true;
        //con un break también te vale y te puedes ahorrar el seteo de nueva_carta a true
    }
}


print_r($primeraCarta);
print_r($segundaCarta);
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo por si te es de utilidad, 
Lo que hice fue hacer el producto cartesiano entre palos y números, así creamos la baraja para luego repartir cartas como si de la realidad se tratase.

La función del producto cartesiano la tome de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15973172/7721477)

```
$palos = array("P","T","C","D");
$cartas = array('2','3','4','5');

//hacemos el producto cartesiano entre números y palos, para obtener las cartas de la baraja
$baraja = cartesian([$palos,$cartas]);

//barajamos
shuffle($baraja);

//quitamos 5 cartas de la baraja para el jugador uno
echo "Cartas jugador 1".PHP_EOL;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $carta = array_shift($baraja); //array_pop() si te gusta dar de abajo :P
    echo "palo:".$carta[0]." numero:".$carta[1].PHP_EOL;
}

//quitamos otras 5 cartas de lo que resta de la baraja para el jugador dos
echo "Cartas jugador 2".PHP_EOL;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $carta = array_shift($baraja); //array_pop() si te gusta dar de abajo :P
    echo "palo:".$carta[0]." numero:".$carta[1].PHP_EOL;
}

//funcion para crear el producto cartesiano
function cartesian($input) {
    $result = array(array());

    foreach ($input as $key => $values) {
        $append = array();

        foreach($result as $product) {
            foreach($values as $item) {

                $product[$key] = $item;
                $append[] = $product;
            }
        }

        $result = $append;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

[Aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e1895c2fe4c04ef4b887bfee957e238e7880fdc) puedes ver un sandbox con el ejemplo en funcionamiento.

Saludos!